# Add seconds to a timestamp in JS (React)

Tags: javascript

For an app, I'm using a OAuth token. In the response, I get the number of seconds until the token expires from now.
So I want to have the timestamp where the token is not good anymore.
I need to add this number of seconds to the current timestamp.

I tried this but this don't give me a future timestamp :

```
let now = new Date().getTime(); <-- CURRENT TIMESTAMP
let expiresIn = body.expires_in; <-- NUMBER OF SECONDS UNTIL THE TOKEN EXPIRES
let timestampWhereTokenExpires = now + expiresIn; <-- TIMESTAMP WHERE THE TOKEN EXPIRES BUT IT GIVES ME THE CURRENT TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: [`new Date().getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns milliseconds.

Comment: oh thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with `new Date().getTime()` as far i know. Following should work in your case:

```
let expiresInMS = 60000;    // let say expiration in 60 s / 1 min
let now = new Date();
let expiresDateTime = new Date(now.getTime() + expiresInMS);
```

**Example in Javascript with some HMTL**

```js
function computeExpired(){
    let expiresInMS = 60000;    // let say expiration in 60 s / 1 min
    let now = new Date();
    let expiresDateTime = new Date(now.getTime() + expiresInMS);

// populate values to HTML elements
document.getElementById('now').innerHTML = now.toLocaleString();
document.getElementById('expiresDateTime').innerHTML = expiresDateTime.toLocaleString();

// console logging
  console.log(now.toLocaleString())
    console.log(expiresDateTime.toLocaleString());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Compute Expiration Date </h3>
<p>let say expiration should occure in 60 s / 1 min from now!</p>

<button onclick="computeExpired()">START</button>
<br>
<p>Now is: <p id="now"></p></span>
<p>Will expire at: <p id="expiresDateTime"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully, this example helps you out (view full page when running the program)!